# hybridauth returning invalid user when trying to login as an open graph test user

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, drupal-7, hybridauth

I'm using hybridauth to to create a open graph action and its workign if I login with developer or testing roles, but when I try to login as an open graph test user, I get the following error.

```
Exception: Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id. in Hybrid_Auth::initialize() (line 147 of /var/www/sites/all/libraries/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php).
```

Any work around for this? My open graph `news.reads` action has been rejected as the open graph test user did not work and I could not publish 'actions' to the timeline (using open graph test user).

I'm using drupal hybridauth module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest 7.x-2.x-dev release and the latest HybridAuth library